# Codename One - TextField letters disappear

Tags: codenameone

In my GUI built app, I insert text in the TextField, then if I press on any other part of the app, the letters in the TF disappear. This didn't happen a couple days ago.

Was there a change in the code in CN1? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue that was recently fixed in text input on Android relating to this. I suggest trying a recent build and verifying that it still happens.